# Same code used in multiple functions but with minor differences - how to optimize?

Tags: python, function, optimization

This is the code of a Udacity course, and I changed it a little. Now, when it runs, it asks me for a movie name and the trailer would open in a pop up in a browser (that's another part, which is not shown).

As you can see, this program has a lot of repetitive code in it, the functions `extract_name`, `movie_poster_url` and `movie_trailer_url` have kind of the same code. Is there a way to get rid of the same code being repeated but have the same output? If so, will it run faster?

```
import fresh_tomatoes
import media
import urllib
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

name = raw_input("Enter movie name:- ")
global movie_name

def extract_html(name):
    url = "website name" + name + "continuation of website name" + name + "again continuation of web site name"
    response = requests.get(url)
    page = str(BeautifulSoup(response.content))
    return page

def extract_name(page):
    start_link = page.find(' - IMDb</a></h3><div class="s"><div class="kv"')
    start_url = page.find('>',start_link-140)
    start_url1 = page.find('>', start_link-140)
    end_url = page.find(' - IMDb</a>', start_link-140)
    name_of_movie = page[start_url1+1:end_url]
    return extract_char(name_of_movie)

def extract_char(name_of_movie):
    name_array = []
    for words in name_of_movie:
        word = words.strip('</b>,')
        name_array.append(word)
    return ''.join(name_array)

def movie_poster_url(name_of_movie):
    movie_name, seperator, tail = name_of_movie.partition(' (')
    #movie_name = name_of_movie.rstrip('()0123456789 ')
    page = urllib.urlopen('another web site name' + movie_name + 'continuation of website name').read()
    start_link = page.find('"Poster":')
    start_url = page.find('"',start_link+9)
    end_url = page.find('"',start_url+1)
    poster_url = page[start_url+1:end_url]
    return poster_url

def movie_trailer_url(name_of_movie):
     movie_name, seperator, tail = name_of_movie.partition(' (')
#movie_name = name_of_movie.rstrip('()0123456789 ')
    page = urllib.urlopen('another website name' + movie_name + " trailer").read()
    start_link = page.find('<div class="yt-lockup-dismissable"><div class="yt-lockup-thumbnail contains-addto"><a aria-hidden="true" href=')
    start_url = page.find('"',start_link+110)
    end_url = page.find('" ',start_url+1)
    trailer_url1 = page[start_url+1:end_url]
    trailer_url = "www.youtube.com" + trailer_url1
    return trailer_url

page = extract_html(name)
movie_name = extract_name(page)
new_movie = media.Movie(movie_name, "Storyline WOW", movie_poster_url(movie_name), movie_trailer_url(movie_name))
movies = [new_movie]
fresh_tomatoes.open_movies_page(movies)
```

Comment: Concerning profiling, read this first: https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the shared parts into their own function:

```
def find_page(url, name, find, offset):
    movie_name, seperator, tail = name_of_movie.partition(' (')
    page = urllib.urlopen(url.format(name)).read()
    start_link = page.find(find)
    start_url = page.find('"',start_link+offset)
    end_url = page.find('" ',start_url+1)
    return page[start_url+1:end_url]


def movie_poster_url(name_of_movie):
    return find_page("another website name{} continuation of website name", name_of_movie, '"Poster":', 9)

def movie_trailer_url(name_of_movie):
    trailer_url = find_page("another website name{} trailer", name_of_movie, '<div class="yt-lockup-dismissable"><div class="yt-lockup-thumbnail contains-addto"><a aria-hidden="true" href=', 110)
    return "www.youtube.com" + trailer_url
```

It definetely wont run faster (there is extra work to do to "switch" between the functions) but the performance difference is probably negligable.

For your second question: Profiling is not a technique or method, it's "finding out what's being bad" in your code:

> Profiling is a form of
>   dynamic program analysis that measures, for example, the space
>   (memory) or time complexity of a program, the usage of particular
>   instructions, or the frequency and duration of function calls. 
>   [(wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming))

So it's not something that speeds up your program, it's a word for things you do to **find out what *you* can do** to speed up your program.

Answer (score 0):

Going really quickly here because I am a super newb but I can see the repetition; what I would do is to figure out the (mostly) repeating blocks of code shared by all 3 functions and then figure out where they differ; write a new function that takes the differences as the arguments. so for instance:

```
def extract(tarString,delim,startDiff,endDiff):
    start_link = page.find(tarString)
    start_url = page.find(delim,start_link+startDiff)
    end_url = page.find(delim,start_url+endDiff)
    url_out = page[start_url+1:end_url]
```

Then, in your poster, trailer, etc functions, just call this extract function with the appropriate arguments for each case. ie poster would call

```
poster_url=extract(tarString='"Poster:"',delim='"',startDiff=9, endDiff=1)
```

I can see you've got another answer already and it's very likely it's written by someone who knows more than I do, but I hope you get something out of my "philosophy of modularizing" from a newbie perspective.